# Also including NULL rows in MySQL SELECT Query

Tags: php, mysql, database

We are trying to select from several tables on a MySQL database.

Our query is:

```
SELECT r.reviews_id, 
       r.customers_name,
       r.date_added,
       rd.reviews_text,
       r.reviews_rating,
       c.customers_email_address
FROM reviews r, reviews_description rd, customers c
WHERE r.customers_id = c.customers_id
  AND r.reviews_id = rd.reviews_id
  AND r.products_id = '74'
  AND r.approved='1'
ORDER BY LENGTH(rd.reviews_text) DESC
```

However, the table `reviews` also has NULL entries on the field `customers_id`

The command `WHERE r.customers_id = c.customers_id` is limiting it to only fields that have a `customers_id`

I was wondering how we can also select the NULL fields?

We have tried `WHERE (r.customers_id = c.customers_id) OR (r.customers_id IS NULL)` - but this does not work.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: or condition should be like this (r.customers_id = c.customers_id  OR r.customers_id IS NULL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the old implicit join syntax. Use explicit joins - in this case a `left join`

```
select r.reviews_id, r.customers_name, r.date_added, rd.reviews_text, r.reviews_rating, 
       c.customers_email_address 
FROM reviews r
INNER JOIN reviews_description rd ON r.reviews_id = rd.reviews_id
LEFT JOIN customers c ON r.customers_id = c.customers_id 
WHERE r.products_id = '74' 
AND r.approved='1' 
ORDER BY LENGTH(rd.reviews_text) DESC
```

Comment: However, the query seems a little slow.  Is there any way to optimize this?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, read about indexes. But since you use a function in the `order by` the query can only be improved on the filter conditions in the `where` clause.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Would removing the LENGTH function improve performance you think?

Comment: It would. Just remove the `order by` clause.

Answer (score -2):

It should be this :

```
WHERE (r.customers_id = c.customers_id = 0 OR r.customers_id IS NULL)
```

Instead of this :

```
WHERE (r.customers_id = c.customers_id) OR (r.customers_id IS NULL)
```